# C (gcc) warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type when calling pthread_cleanup_push()

Tags: c, pthreads, void-pointers

gcc version 4.3.3 under Ubuntu Linux 9.04 in case that is relevant.

This is the offending code:

```
pthread_cleanup_push(ctl_cleanup, NULL);
```

with ctl_cleanup() defined as

```
void* ctl_cleanup(void *arg);
```

There are other instances where this warning pops up, in similar circumstances. The warning also appears if I call something like

```
pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, (void *)&m);
```

where m is of type pthread_mutex_t. The warning reads:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

I don't understand. I've passed other things around using void pointers (e.g. when passing arguments to a pthread) without that warning. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Given Seth's solution, I've found that the GNU C Library Documentation contains an error on pg. 437. They use pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, (void *) &mut); when in fact you need to cast the pthread_mutex_unlock to type (void *) which generated the error above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void ctl_cleanup(void *arg);
```

The above is the prototype you are looking for.  It returns void, not a pointer to void.

The extra * in the function is because it takes a pointer to a function taking one void* argument returning void.