# pthread_cleanup_push with pthread_mutex_unlock

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have following code in C:

```
pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &mutex);
```

however when I compile it, I get the following warning:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

What's wrong? It looks like the cleanup handler should return void*, not int. Is there any way to bypass this warning without writing additional wrapper?

Comment: This is a perfectly clear warning. What part of it do you struggle with? Have you read the manuals of all the functions that are involved here?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119140/c-gcc-warning-initialization-from-incompatible-pointer-type-when-calling-pthr)

Comment: Both of you missed the actual question.

Comment: You need the wrapper.

Comment: BTW I don't get what's up with all the -1's... This is a legitimate question.

Comment: Some people just have trouble with reading the whole question before answering. A typical day on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `pthread_mutex_unlock` does not have type `void (*)(void *)`. You need to wrap it:

```
static void cleanup_unlock_mutex(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(p);
}
```

and pass this function's address to `pthread_cleanup_push`.

Others may advise you to just cast `pthread_mutex_unlock`, but this is incorrect and unsafe. It will cause the function to be called via a pointer to the wrong function type, resulting in undefined behavior.